# Show split 3D view with and without rig?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to pose my characters face, but with so many rig layers on top for control, it's hard to see if I'm doing the right tweaks. I want to have two windows, one with my rig controls and one without, but the changes to viewport are global.

My current work around is to have the render result and then use F12 each time, but it would be awesome with live update. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Did you try turning off bones overlay in one of the viewports? It worked for me. Here is the same window with two viewports:
https://i.imgur.com/hxaL4F4.png
https://i.imgur.com/BaBsFTL.png

Comment: awesome that worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blender 2.8+, you can disable to overlay button in the top right corner. In 2.79, you can press N and check "only render" to only see the object in your scene. Hope this helps!